# Disable Gravity forms scroll to top in elementor

Tags: wordpress, scroll, gravity-forms-plugin, elementor

I've got a problem. I'm currently working for a client in an Wordpress buildup with Elementor. They have a form made with GravityForms.

When I submit the form it automaticly scrolls to top. I want it to do nothing more than submit the form. So... no scrolling.

I found out I can 'easy' set it off. But it won't work over here

https://docs.gravityforms.com/disable-automatic-scroll-form-confirmation/

On some other websites I found they said 'Place it in the functions.php'.

So I did, I had no idea where specific in the fuctions.php... but It didn't work on top neither on the bottom.

Other websites told me to work in the theme files (since there is no theme because I'm using Elementor I can't find where...

The docs.gravityforms.com told me to paste it in form_display.php...

Whatever... Where ever I post the 'easy' line of code. It wont work...

Can somebody please help me out.
Where specefic do I have the place this line of code

add_filter( 'gform_confirmation_anchor', '__return_false' );

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 0):

functions.php is a Theme File that you cam Access From WordPress Dashboard>> Apperence>> Theme Editor >> and now look for the right panel http://prntscr.com/prb6v2

After opening the functions.php file put that line of code at the bottom of it & Save.

However, It's recommended to do such Theme file edit via child theme otherwise you will lose your edit's after next theme update.

Comment: Thanks Ferdous, but as I stated, there is no template in use since I use Elementor. So there is also no option in the menu. Dashboard > Apperence >> Theme editor... This is not in the menu.

I've just followed that direction in the FTP. (themes>twentyninteen>functions.php) and pasted it at the bottom & saved. But as I've said before. This also didn't work.

Comment: Are you using any Managed WordPress Hosting? If so then they could be disabled the Theme Editor from WP Dashboard.

By the way, Are you sure your currently active theme is Twentyninteen?

Answer (score 0):

That link and snippet at https://docs.gravityforms.com/disable-automatic-scroll-form-confirmation/ is to prevent the confirmation message appear in the viewport. On submission the form displays the confirmation message above the position where the start of the form would have been. Years ago, the default behaviour was that after a long form, you could submit and be way down the viewport and miss the confirmation message.

This this snippet used to be a way for getting around this and would jump you back up the viewport. But now "When a form is submitted, the default behaviour of Gravity Forms is to scroll to the confirmation message"

So it look like this snippet is now used to prevent the old behaviour, so you're in the right place.

I would use a child them and add the code to the child theme functions.php file, otherwise it may get overwritten when the parent theme is updated.